# http put when user closes browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm trying to issue a put request to save some stuff when the user closes the browser.
I'm using angular and I've tried using the onbeforeunload and onunload events but not getting it to work the way I want. I have a Resource i want to update.

```
    $window.onbeforeunload = function(){
       myResource.foo = closingBrowser();
       myResource.$update();}
```

With fiddler running I see that this does not do a put request. Not when I use `$window.onunload`either. But if i enter a return statement to `onbeforeunload` the confirmation box pops up, and when I click OK, fiddler shows that the put request is done. Now I don't want this popup, I just want to PUT when the user closes the browser.

Is there a way for me to do this with these methods or must I solve it some other way (advise much appreciated)?

**Update:**

I did some more testing and found some inconsistent behavior. In Internet explorer (11): If I have the return statement, there is the classic popup. But it only sends the PUT if I press cancel and return to the page. If I press OK to leave, the PUT is not issued.

In chrome: It does not matter if I press cancel to return, or Ok to leave, the PUT is still sent. Another 'hack'(?) that worked in chrome but not ie, when not having a return (no popup, which is wanted behavior), was to have a loop after the `$update()`, something like: `while(!myResource.$resolved){}` (or just a for-loop iterating a few million times also worked, but it looked uglier,) chrome actually sends the PUT (IE did not).

How do you suppose this would be replicated in IE?

I did not do extensive test on firefox, but the little I did, it seemed more like chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can't escape this popup ("Do you want close this window bla bla bla..."). 
I think the best solution is next:

1. If user close current tab, browser will show popup with your text
2. You send http put request to server, when http request will call success callback you will, show custom popup("Your settings or something another was saved bla bla bla)
3. Close window by using window.close

Comment: Is there no way to send http put without the popup? I don't want to keep the user on the page or anything, just send a put when the browser or tab is closed.

Comment: If page will be closed, browser will abort your put query

Answer (score 0):

I think nowadays you can use Service Worker to handle that.

It's possible to postMessage to ServiceWorker onbeforeunload and do the request. It's also possible to ping the service worker and detect when app stopped pinging from sw side, then do PUT request.